# Python3 compare data from DB and write the answer back to DB

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, cgi, survey

[Introduction]

I am currently creating a web application in Python 3.7.4 over CGI. (the web server does not support wsgi)

The application is a simple survey were users answer questions into a carousel form.
Answers are written in the DB (MySql) according to the respondentID.
No problems until now. Everything is working fine.

However, I have been asked to insert a logic into the survey and display results according to it.

[Objective]

Lets say I have 30 questions and users can answer 0, 1 or 2 for each of them.
Answers are processed only when the user complete the survey.
At completion, data are stored as integer inside DB as si001, si002, si003,....si030

If there are values inside the DB, I would like to count how many of each possible answer have been recorded. For example, how many 0s, how many 1s, how many 2s.

The results will be recorded inside the DB in different columns. (simaru, sisankaku, sibatsu)
What I would like to do is something similar to the code below. (code is obviously wrong)
I know the SELECT status from the DB can be summarized in one cursor.execute only, but for the time being (logic details are yet to be completed) I would like to left it as it is.

[CODE]

```
@app.route('/results1', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def results1():
# Check survey completion status
cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM private_survey WHERE privateid = %s', (session['username'],))
account = cursor.fetchone()
if account['surveystatus'] == 'Available' or account['surveystatus'] == 'Started':
    # Check survey status, if available redirect to noresults
    return redirect(url_for('noresults'))
else:
    # Survey already completed, show results1
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cursor.execute('SELECT si001, si002, si003, si004, si005, si006, si007, si008, si009, si010, si011, si012, si013, si014, si015, si016, si017, si018, si019, si020, si021, si022, si023, si024, si025, si026, si027, si028, si029, si030 FROM private_survey INNER JOIN private_survey_answers ON private_survey.surveyid=private_survey_answers.surveyid WHERE private_survey.privateid=%s', (session['username'],))
    answer1 = cursor.fetchone()
    maru = 0
    sankaku = 0
    batsu = 0
    simaru = 0
    sisankaku = 0
    sibatsu = 0
    for x in answer1:
        if x == 2:
            simaru = maru + 1
        if x == 1:
            sisankaku = sankaku + 1
        if x == 0:
            sibatsu = batsu + 1
        cursor.execute('UPDATE private_survey_answers INNER JOIN private_survey ON private_survey.surveyid=private_survey_answers.surveyid SET simaru = %s, sisankaku = %s, sibatsu = %s WHERE private_survey.privateid = %s', (simaru, sisankaku, sibatsu, session['username'],))
        mysql.connection.commit()
    return render_template('results1.html', answer1=answer1, account=account)
```

Any help or idea would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using the count function.
The solution I found is both able to display the count in real time and write it in the DB for CSV download, etc..

```
@app.route('/results1', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def results1():
# Check survey completion status
cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM private_survey WHERE privateid = %s', (session['username'],))
account = cursor.fetchone()
if account['surveystatus'] == 'Available' or account['surveystatus'] == '開始':
    # Check survey status, if available redirect to noresults
    return redirect(url_for('noresults'))
else:
    # Survey already completed, show results1
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    cursor.execute('SELECT si001, si002, si003, si004, si005, si006, si007, si008, si009, si010, si011, si012, si013, si014, si015, si016, si017, si018, si019, si020, si021, si022, si023, si024, si025, si026, si027, si028, si029, si030 FROM private_survey INNER JOIN private_survey_answers ON private_survey.surveyid=private_survey_answers.surveyid WHERE private_survey.privateid=%s', (session['username'],))
    answer1 = cursor.fetchone()
    cnt = [answer1['si001'], answer1['si002'], answer1['si003'], answer1['si004'], answer1['si005']]
    cnt.count(2)
    cnt.count(1)
    cnt.count(0)
    cursor.execute('UPDATE private_survey_answers INNER JOIN private_survey ON private_survey.surveyid=private_survey_answers.surveyid SET simaru = %s, sisankaku = %s, sibatsu = %s WHERE private_survey.privateid = %s', (cnt.count(2), cnt.count(1), cnt.count(0), session['username'],))
    mysql.connection.commit()
    return render_template('results1.html', answer1=answer1, account=account, cnt=cnt)
```